# package.json scripts can't be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have two scripts in my package.json file:

```
"scripts":
{
    "test": "browserify js/test.js -o js/test_bundle.js --debug",
    "main": "browserify js/main.js -o js/main_bundle.js --debug"
}
```

The first works just fine in the console (Windows 7):

[image]

But the second gives an error:

[image]

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to : `npm run main`

Custom npm scripts, need to be run that way.

Default ones, such as `start`, `test` ... can be run directly.

See doc: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Answer (score 1):

you need to run

```
npm run-script main
```

npm test is just short for npm run-script test